# There was an error while Opening file handle

Tags: visual-studio-code

Okay so I am trying to update my VS Code but every time I click on restart to update I get the error message saying that :

**"There was an error while Opening file handle: C:\Users\neela\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\logs\custom-scanner-service.log": failed to create file handle: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.**

**Please read the log file for more information :
C:\Users\neela\AppData\Local\Temp\vscode-inno-updater-1624166774.log**

After I opened the log file mentioned above here's what it says :
**Jun 20 11:00:03.966 ERRO Failed to create file handle: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.**

Can someone please guide me on this situation.

Comment: Do you have another copy of VSCode running in the background?

Answer (score 27):

I had faced the same problem for two days. Then I ran the vs code as administrator and check for update manually from the top help menu. It got updated successfully then.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me too, although under the help menu it already said "Restart to Update", so I tried it again while running VS Code as admin and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

I tried taking ownership of the %appdata% vs code files, but ultimately I still ended up needing to run the update as admin.

Answer (score 0):

start>right click vs code>file location>right click & open properties>compatibility tab>run as administrator.
restart vscode. This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

run your VScode as administrator, then go to setting at the bottom left. Click Check for Updates. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Running VS Code in admin didn't work for me as the option "check for updates" was not there in the "Help" menu.

Only way I managed to resolve it is by restarting VS Code from my Windows terminal which downloaded and installed the update.